# ¿ Cómo maximizar una subventana contenida en un MdiArea con Pyqt4?

Tags: python-2.7, qt, pyqt

Estoy trabajando con PyQt4 y Qt Designer 4, y estoy manejando subventanas con QMdiArea, pero al ejecutar el programa las subventanas contenidas dentro del MdiArea salen pequeñas (aplastadas). Necesito que la ventana que esta activa se maximice automaticamente. He usado el metodo showMaximized() pero maximiza la ventana por fuera de MdiArea.

El modulo "seleccion_turno" es un modulo que convertí de un archivo .ui hecho con Qt Designer 4 y este archivo es donde esta hecha la interfaz gráfica

A continuación muestro mi código y el programa como sale al ejecutarlo.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtTest
from seleccion_turno import *

class MyForm(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self,parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.mdiArea.addSubWindow(self.ui.subwindow)
        self.ui.mdiArea.addSubWindow(self.ui.subwindow_2)
        self.ui.mdiArea.addSubWindow(self.ui.subwindow_3)    

if __name__== "__main_":
    app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyForm()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: así salen las ventanas del MdiArea al ejecutar el programa]

Quiero que se maximice la primera subwindow que agregue

Acá está el archivo seleccion_turno.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'seleccion_turno.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.11.4
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(802, 555)
        MainWindow.setWindowOpacity(1.0)
        MainWindow.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayout"))
        self.mdiArea = QtGui.QMdiArea(self.centralwidget)
        sizePolicy = QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(10)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(10)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.mdiArea.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.mdiArea.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.mdiArea.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(781, 0))
        self.mdiArea.setSizeIncrement(QtCore.QSize(10, 10))
        self.mdiArea.setBaseSize(QtCore.QSize(10, 10))
        self.mdiArea.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("mdiArea"))
        self.subwindow = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.subwindow.setBaseSize(QtCore.QSize(10, 10))
        self.subwindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("subwindow"))
        self.escudo = QtGui.QLabel(self.subwindow)
        self.escudo.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 211, 241))
        self.escudo.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("border-image: url(:/descarga);"))
        self.escudo.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("escudo"))
        self.titulo_ventana2 = QtGui.QLabel(self.subwindow)
        self.titulo_ventana2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 10, 461, 231))
        self.titulo_ventana2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("titulo_ventana2"))
        self.btn_continuar = QtGui.QPushButton(self.subwindow)
        self.btn_continuar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 360, 511, 91))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(26)
        self.btn_continuar.setFont(font)
        self.btn_continuar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("btn_continuar"))
        self.flecha_ventana1 = QtGui.QGraphicsView(self.subwindow)
        self.flecha_ventana1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 220, 131, 151))
        self.flecha_ventana1.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("border-image: url(:/flecha_hacia_abajo.gif);"))
        self.flecha_ventana1.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("flecha_ventana1"))
        self.subwindow_2 = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.subwindow_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("subwindow_2"))
        self.titulo_ventana2_2 = QtGui.QLabel(self.subwindow_2)
        self.titulo_ventana2_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 10, 401, 51))
        self.titulo_ventana2_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("titulo_ventana2_2"))
        self.btn_liq_2clase = QtGui.QPushButton(self.subwindow_2)
        self.btn_liq_2clase.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 90, 321, 91))
        self.btn_liq_2clase.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("btn_liq_2clase"))
        self.btn_liq_dupl = QtGui.QPushButton(self.subwindow_2)
        self.btn_liq_dupl.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 330, 321, 91))
        self.btn_liq_dupl.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("btn_liq_dupl"))
        self.btn_liq_prov = QtGui.QPushButton(self.subwindow_2)
        self.btn_liq_prov.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 210, 321, 91))
        self.btn_liq_prov.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("btn_liq_prov"))
        self.btn_consulta = QtGui.QPushButton(self.subwindow_2)
        self.btn_consulta.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(370, 90, 321, 91))
        self.btn_consulta.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("btn_consulta"))
        self.btn_recibos = QtGui.QPushButton(self.subwindow_2)
        self.btn_recibos.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(370, 210, 321, 91))
        self.btn_recibos.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("btn_recibos"))
        self.btn_libretas = QtGui.QPushButton(self.subwindow_2)
        self.btn_libretas.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(370, 330, 321, 91))
        self.btn_libretas.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("btn_libretas"))
        self.subwindow_3 = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.subwindow_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("subwindow_3"))
        self.titulo_ventana3 = QtGui.QLabel(self.subwindow_3)
        self.titulo_ventana3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 10, 551, 321))
        self.titulo_ventana3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("titulo_ventana3"))
        self.flecha_ventana3 = QtGui.QGraphicsView(self.subwindow_3)
        self.flecha_ventana3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 340, 141, 131))
        self.flecha_ventana3.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("border-image: url(:/flecha_hacia_abajo.gif);"))
        self.flecha_ventana3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("flecha_ventana3"))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.mdiArea, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 802, 27))
        self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None))
        self.subwindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Subwindow", None))
        self.escudo.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p><br/></p></body></html>", None))
        self.titulo_ventana2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:28pt; font-weight:600;\">DISTRITO MILITAR Nº 7</span></p><p align=\"center\"><br/></p><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:36pt; font-weight:600;\">¡ BIENVENIDO !</span></p><p><br/></p></body></html>", None))
        self.btn_continuar.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PRESIONE PARA CONTINUAR", None))
        self.subwindow_2.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Subwindow", None))
        self.titulo_ventana2_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:28pt; font-weight:600;\">SELECCIONE SERVICIO</span></p></body></html>", None))
        self.btn_liq_2clase.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "LIQUIDACIÓN LIBRETA DE 2 CLASE", None))
        self.btn_liq_dupl.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "LIQUIDACIÓN DUPLICADO", None))
        self.btn_liq_prov.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "LIQUIDACIÓN PROVISIONAL", None))
        self.btn_consulta.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "CONSULTA", None))
        self.btn_recibos.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ENTREGA RECIBOS", None))
        self.btn_libretas.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ENTREGA LIBRETAS", None))
        self.subwindow_3.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Subwindow", None))
        self.titulo_ventana3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:26pt; font-weight:600;\">¡ GRACIAS POR ACUDIR AL</span></p><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:26pt; font-weight:600;\">DISTRITO MILITAR Nº7 !</span></p><p align=\"center\"><br/></p><p align=\"center\"><br/></p><p align=\"center\"><br/></p><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:26pt; font-weight:600;\">TOME SU TURNO</span></p></body></html>", None))

import imagenes
```

Por favor si alguien me puede ayudar estaré muy agradecido.

Comment: jajaja, la misma pregunta, como comente en el otro post, no has usado layout por lo que el widget tiene como sizeHint() a 0,0 por lo que al establecerlo como maximized() toma toda la ventana, podria ayudarte si me compartes el .ui y todo los demas recursos como el .qrc, las imagenes a traves de dropbox o similares, :D

Comment: Como te comento, para ti seria mas util que te responda por aca ya que el idioma puede ser un incoveniente, asi que te pido que elimines tu pregunta en SO en inglés, y solo usemos esta pregunta.

Comment: Uff, gracias,¿ como es tu correo de Drive para compartir los archivos ?

Comment: No es necesario que te de mi correo, haz click derecho en la carpeta de drive donde este el proyecto y una de las opciones del menu dice: "obtener enlace para compartir", seleccionalo y comparteme el enlace.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1M2IwxOn8qnR7xfvnWOFXvtcBYQNuY0aP

Comment: El archivo principal es el que se llama ejecutable.py, ahí es donde tengo el código que mostré al principio pero con otras cosas adicionales, tambien esta el .ui y el .qrc. Los demás archivos son otras cosas que uso para el proyecto.